# What is the frequency threshold for google cloud messaging throttling

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, throttling

As https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling indicates ,

> Blockquote and to optimize for the overall network efficiency and battery life of devices, GCM implements throttling of messages using a token bucket scheme. Messages are throttled on a per application and per collapse key basis (including non-collapsible messages). Each application collapse key is granted some initial tokens, and new tokens are granted periodically therefter. Each token is valid for a single message sent to the device. If an application collapse key exhausts its supply of available tokens, new messages are buffered in a pending queue until new tokens become available at the time of the periodic grant.

Is there any exact threshold or related data implying a proper sending frequency?

Comment: Did you find any concrete numbers?